# Is the commutator relation $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}_x]=i\hbar 1\!\!1$ an *assumption* in the quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, commutator, foundations

This question is somewhat related to (but *not* by any means the same as) the [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/553676/) I asked recently.

In his *Lectures on Quantum Theory*, Isham essentially says (reference given below) that if an operator $\hat{d}_x$ satisfies $[\hat{x}, \hat{d}_x] = i\hbar 1\!\!1$ (where $\hat{x}$ is the familiar operator corresponding to position), then *"by appealing to the classical limit of the theory, or by requiring consistency with the results of elementary wave mechanics"*, we can conclude $\hat{d}_x = \hat{p}_x$.

**Questions:**

1. If Isham is building the axiomatic framework for QM, how can he conclude this by demanding consistency with elementary wave mechanics which is just a special case of his more general formalism, and which also lacks a proper formalism (in his book at least)?
2. Also, wouldn't appealing to *the classical limit* of the theory be circular if the theory has not been developed in the first case? Or is it a forcing condition we apply on the theory that we're building to account for the observed classical phenomena?
3. In any case, can someone *clearly* answer whether $[\hat{x}, \hat{d}_x] = i\hbar 1\!\!1$ is *assumed in the foundations*, or is it *derivable*, or is it *imposable as some classical limit* (in the sense of the latter part of the second question)?

---

Reference: Section 7.2.2 *Displaced Observers and the Canonical Commutation Relations*, page 137 (bottom), point 10.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14py4099PEubyxH5MYUHt8gsY0eSiFC6Y/view?usp=drivesdk) to my copy of Isham's book.

Comment: Regarding your point 3, do you mean can someone answer whether $[x,p]=i\hbar$ is an assumption or derivable? Because what you wrote is clearly derived by Isham as you mention in your previous question.

Comment: @DvijD.C. In the previous, I ask how he so-called "derived" what he claims. Sorry for the late reply though, I slept... :)

Comment: Normally, the Heisenberg/Born relation is a cornerstone QM postulate, comporting with the vision of Dirac's PhD dissertation on the correspondence principle. I should not be familiar with what Isham's book assumes.